# "Namba forcing adds reals" independent of $ZFC + \neg CH$?

Tags: set-theory, forcing

I know that, in the presence of $CH$, Namba forcing does not add reals. But when $CH$ fails, is it consistent that it still does not add reals?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If CH fails, then Nm adds reals (or equivalently, new $\omega$-sequences of reals).

Proof:  Let $f:\omega_2\to 2^\omega$ be 1-1.  Let $\bar \alpha:=(\alpha_n:n\in \omega)$ be the name for the Namba sequence in $\omega_2$.  Then $x:=(f(\alpha_n):n\in \omega)$ is the name of a new sequence of reals.  The sequence $x$ is new because $\bar\alpha$ can be computed from $x$.

Comment: How do you get a new real from the $\omega$-sequence?

Comment: @Zoorado: Pick your favorite bijection in the ground model between $\omega$ and $\omega^2$, and use it to encode the sequence into a single real.